# Proof for linear algebra exercise requires determinant of non square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

Question: Any transformation or square matrix has a minimal polynomial. Does the converse hold?

Solution: Yes. Expand down the last column to check that $\displaystyle x^{n}+m_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots +m_{1}x+m_{0}$ is plus or minus the determinant of this.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
-x  &0  &0  &      &    &m_0    \\
0  &1-x&0  &      &    &m_1    \\
0  &0  &1-x&      &    &m_2    \\
&   &   &\ddots             \\
&   &   &      &1-x &m_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}$$

I'm not sure what is being meant here. It seems as though the proof requires taking the determinant of this matrix that is not square which to my understanding is not possible. Am i misinterpreting something?

Comment: I think you want to take the determinant ( actually the minimum polynomial) of the companion matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix . The matrix is square

Comment: The question is extremely poorly worded and is misusing the word "converse".  It appears that the intended meaning was: "is every polynomial the minimal polynomial of some square matrix"?

Comment: Where does this question come from? Would you please cite the source?

Comment: @user1551 https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Polynomials_of_Maps_and_Matrices problem 22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the author of the solution has a made a very strange combination of errors. I believe that the matrix *should* be
$$
\pmatrix{x &&&&&m_0\\ 
-1&x &&&&m_1\\
&\ddots&\ddots & &&\vdots\\
&&-1&x\\
&&&-1&x& m_{n-2}\\
&&&&-1&x+m_{n-1}},
$$
which is equal to $xI - C$ where $C$ is the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the polynomial.

Comment: This looks to be correct but how do we know the resulting polynomial is minimal for C?

Comment: @Eggue it suffices to note that the set $\{v,Cv,\dots,C^{n-1}v\}$ is linearly independent where $v = (1,0,\dots,0)^T$.